# How to solve "flutterfire configure" on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I follow firebase instructions for connecting firebase with flutter project. My some commands succesfylly. Also my firebase account created. But I have problem while running command `flutterfire configure` . Before it all commands run successfully.

When I run command `flutterfire configure` in root directory of my project. It give me response:

> PS E:\House Budget\expence_tracker\meals\meals> flutterfire configure
> Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

Comment: you have installed git on your system?